# Unpublish Authors With not Fulfilled Fields

Tags: author, meta-query, pre-get-posts, author-template

I want to unpublish profiles of users that doesn't have all extra fields that I've created filled.

I use a custom `meta_query` in a user taxonomy in order to filter those authors, and that work, but it doesn't in `author` templates.

```
function unpublish_not_full_authors( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            // your code to set $current_user_name here
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                  'key'     => 'descripcion_breve',
                  'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                ),
                array(
                  'key'     => 'titulacion_preparador',
                  'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                ),
              )
            );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'unpublish_not_full_authors' );
```

**EDIT TO CLARIFY:**

When a users register in my site he/she gets an URL to his website: example.com/author/my_profile.

What I want is to "un-publish" this public profile until the author doesn't have filled a few fields that I've created using ACF.

Comment: The problem's description is still unclear to me, like: a) To un-publish something usually means to change the post status from 'publish'. b) what do you mean by a user taxonomy here? c) It's not clear what you mean by a meta query in a user taxonomy. d) What do you mean doesn't work? What kind of errors? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you think you're doing but `pre_get_posts` action has nothing to do with users but posts only. You say you created extra fields, show us how you did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something like this tutorial on [categorizing wordpress users](https://tadpole.cc/blog/user-taxonomies-categorize-wordpress-users/), correct?

I think you should do your filtering in your theme files, not on a hook. Just add an if statement to your template file (probably `author.php`) that tests if your custom fields aren't empty strings, and then do whatever (404, redirect elsewhere, throw a notice...)

Unless you need to specifically have a parameter that says whether an author is public or not (e.g. you're planning to write a back-end user management GUI or something like that), hiding users through theme files should be the easiest way to this.

Comment: You're right, with an IF statement is easier.